# allow only emails from specific domain/subdomain to register and send verification email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Can someone show me how to allow only emails from specific domain/subdomain to submit email in a form. After submission I would like the email to be sent both to the user's email and my own email. I'm not really sure how to integrate it, so that's mostly what I need help with.

Comment: you can use JavaScript or HTML5 input `pattern` attribute to check the domain. Then set up an AJAX request that sends the information to a PHP file that sends the email. Are you familiar with any of this? Let me know if you need some more explanation and I'd be happy to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks buy I don't know how to write the code for it. Any example? I have been looking through stackoverflow but not sure how to integrate it

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer with some info about each step.

Comment: Alright thank you. Can you show me the code too thanks

Comment: I want the form to also only allow domain specific emails to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up a form that will only accept email addresses with certain domains, you can do two things.

The first is to use the HTML5 input `type="email"` attribute, which can be used to make sure that any browser that supports HTML5 can validate the email to at least be a valid one.

HTML file:

```
<form id="contact-form">
    <!-- Other inputs here -->
    <input name="user-email" type="email" id="user-email" placeholder="johnny.appleseed@gmail.com" required>
    <!-- make sure this name="" attribute matches what you ask for in the PHP -->
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Then you can also use JavaScript to check the domain. Once you know that the email is valid and fits your constraints, you will need to set up an AJAX POST that will send data to the server to handle sending the email. This part can be done like so:

JavaScript file:

```
$('#form-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the button from refreshing the page
    var userEmail = $('#user-email');

    if (userEmail.val().indexOf('.com') !== -1) { // validation
        // xyz has .com in it
    } else if (userEmail.val().indexOf('.org') !== -1) { // validation
        // xyz has .org in it      
    } else {
        $('#submission-info').text('Whoops, we don't send emails, to anything other than .org or .com, please enter a different email and try again.');
    }
    // this doesn't mean .com or .org is at the end
    // you may want to check that by using a regular expression if necessary        


    var formData = $('#contact-form').serialize(); // This gets the <form id="contact-form"> element's values and serializes it into a string.

    $.ajax({
        url: 'mail.php', // make sure this file is either in the same directory or the path is changed
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        // do stuff to to show the user that the form was submitted
        $('#submission-info').text('Success, your information has been sent to us (and the NSA of course) and we will reply to you as soon as possible.');
    }).fail(function(response, error) {
        // tell the user what happened that caused the form submission to fail
        $('#submission-info').text('Oh no, something happened. Maybe try again');
    });

});
```

For more info about serializing, check out [jQuery's API page](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Then in mail.php, you can handle it in PHP by doing something like this:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$formcontent = "From: $firstname $lastname \n Email address: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "john.doe@gmail.com"; // your email goes here instead
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

If you use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), then you can do all kinds of stuff and it is somewhat more intuitive and clearer and offers many more options that you can configure.

Using PHPMailer would look something like this for a mail.php file:

```
<?php

require_once("class.phpmailer.php"); // this path should also be set up properly

if ($_POST) { // If something was sent by submitting the form.

    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["user-name"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["user-email"]);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["comment"]);
    $subject = "Contact form";
    $to = "john.doe@gmail.com"; // your email here
    $userBcc = $_POST["user-bcc"]; // You can BCC the user's email

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = "xyz@xyzs.com"; // make sure to change this to something else
    $mail->FromName = "XYZ XYZ"; // change this too.
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
    if($userBcc == true) {
        $mail->addBCC($email);
    }

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

So now you should have a form that works. I would suggest testing it a little bit by just sending emails to yourself and doing test submissions before you make it live. You may also want to implement some form of anti-spam, depending on the audience using the site. Forgive me if I forget anything or it isn't clear, I will edit the post and try to detail/fix anything I can.

Good luck and let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to also send a copy of the form to my email and the email of the person who filled up the form?

Comment: that's what PHPMailer's BCC is for. :)

Comment: hello i followed all your steps but cant seem to get the form to work. also it does not verify whether the email contains .com/.org on submit .

Comment: also what does xyz.indexOf('.com') do?? sorry i am very new to coding and stuff

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Comment: hello it still does not work. please help.

Comment: is it possible ou write a working version and send to me?

Comment: http://ilanbiala.com/test/test/ shows that it works. http://ilanbiala.com/test/test/mail.php gives you the code. You will have to modify it a little and you can remove the `else {...}` statement in the `mail.php` file because that's just to show you the code for each page.